# How to use a collection in vba to update another cell comparing with a value of one cell

Tags: excel, vba, collections

My Excel Sheet:

[image]

My VBA code:

```
Sub popdata()

    Set compreplace = New Collection
    compreplace.Add "AA-", "test@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "BB-", "test2@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "CC-", "test3@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "DD-", "test4@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "EE-", "test5@yahoo.com"

    Call popexcel

End Sub

Function popexcel()
    Dim rc As Integer
    rc = UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Integer  

    For i = 2 To rc
        //fill in "L" column value respective to the row
        //example "L2" should have "AA-" because "K2" value is "test@yahoo.com"
        Range("L" & i).Value = compreplace.Item(Range("K" & i).Value)
    Next i
End Function
```

However I get the following error in VBA:

> Run-time error '5':
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument

Any idea how to resolve this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your function can't "see" the `Collection` *(it is out of scope)*.  Either pass it as an argument or make it `Global`.

Comment: So I updated it and moved the Collection inside the `popexcel` function and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit`, and you'll want to pass `compreplace` to `popexcel` as a parameter (or promote it to module scope).

Comment: So if I actually pass a (string) it works but when I use Range(row,col).Value I get that error... I am guessing I have to convert the .Value to a String before passing?

Comment: `Range.Value` is a `Variant` that can contain any data type, and VBA will happily convert them to a `String` for you - except if the cell contains an `Error` value, in which case neither implicit nor explicit conversion will work: you get a type mismatch error if you try to use an `Error` and compare it or assign it to a `String`. Use the `IsError` function to verify whether a variant is a `Variant/Error`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. The first one is that the collection isn't declared in such a way that both methods can access it. The other problem is that you are not taking care of cases where the address isn't found. Have a look below:

```
Public compreplace As Collection

Sub popdata()    
    Set compreplace = New Collection
    compreplace.Add "AA-", "test@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "BB-", "test2@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "CC-", "test3@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "DD-", "test4@yahoo.com"
    compreplace.Add "EE-", "test5@yahoo.com"

    popexcel

End Sub

Function popexcel()
    Dim rc As Integer
    rc = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To rc
        If ItemExists(compreplace, Range("K" & i).Value) Then
            Range("L" & i).Value = compreplace.item(Range("K" & i).Value)
        End If
    Next i
End Function


Function ItemExists(coll As Collection, item As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.item item
    ItemExists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

The ItemExists function returns true if there is a matching item. The Public declaration at the top makes it available to your pop method. Not the best way, but it works.

Comment: You'll probably want to make `popexcel` a `Private Function`, since there's temporal coupling going on here (using it without having first invoked `popdata` would throw an error) -- passing the collection as a parameter would remove the temporal coupling.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I agree. In this case I tried to reuse the original code as much as possible to keep focus on the problem.

Comment: This is working for me. Thank you. What is the difference from what I was doing, just for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway to also add a condition if the value that will goto "L", then don't insert it... I guess an if statement will suffice there :)

Comment: @Si8 - Your code, as you posted it, will work if all values match. If not, you will get the error you posted. I added a function that tests if a value is available before trying to retrieve it. If it doesn't exist, it does not try.

Comment: @Si8 - I don't understand your second question (goto "L" etc).

Comment: Nevermind, it's not appending the value. It's actually overwriting what's there already, The `L` column so please disregard :)